# One Custom Navigation Bar for more than five View Controllers with button actions

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am new to obj-C. Currently i am implementing navigation based application. In my application I need to show navigation bar along with five buttons to all views(seven view controllers). Instead of crate five buttons in every class I wanted to create single custom navigation controller with five buttons and show it to all view controllers. It is working fine in view controller but not in navigation view controller. Please help me or tell me some examples.

I am calling below code in my first view controller and the button action code implemented in CustomNavBArViewController class.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
CustomNavBarViewController *navBar=[[CustomNavBarViewController alloc]init];
navBar.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
[self.view addSubview:navBar.view];
}
```

When I click on that button the class is calling but action is not performming. But is working for

[self presentModalViewController:createAcc animated:YES]; not for

[self.navigationController pushViewController:createAcc animated:YES];

I need push another view controller, Please help me. Thanks

Comment: When you are pushing it to a view are you popping it out from all other views or not??? pushing too many viewControllers can cause a problem.

Comment: well, probably, you'd better use a tabbar...

Comment: I am not able to push any view controller.